# How to copy end of the Array in swift?

Tags: swift

There must be some really elegant way of copying end of the Array using Swift starting from some index, but I just could not find it, so I ended with this:

```
func getEndOfArray<T>( arr : [T], fromIndex : Int? = 0) -> [T] {
    var i=0;
    var newArray : [T] = [T]()
    for item in arr {
        if i >= fromIndex {
            newArray.append(item)
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return newArray // returns copy of the array starting from index fromIndex
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this without extra function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

And another one ...

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let fromIndex = 2
let endOfArray = array.dropFirst(fromIndex)
print(endOfArray) // [3, 4, 5]
```

This gives an `ArraySlice` which should be good enough for most
purposes. If you need a real `Array`, use

```
let endOfArray = Array(array.dropFirst(fromIndex))
```

An empty array/slice is created if the start index is larger than (or equal to) the element count.

Comment: This was the closest to original question. I guess the real functionality here is the SequenceType -protocol? https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html

Comment: @TeroTolonen: You are right, `dropFirst()` works on any `SequenceType`.

Answer (score 10):

You can use suffix:

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
let lastTwo = array.suffix(2) // [5, 6]
```

As mentioned in the comment: This gives you an `ArraySlice` object which is sufficient for most cases. If you really need an `Array` object you have to cast it:

```
let lastTwoArray = Array(lastTwo)
```

Comment: As for `dropFirst` and `dropLast`, `prefix` and `suffix` return `ArraySlice` objects, so if you need an array, you must pass the result to `Array()`.

Answer (score 8):

You can subscript an open ended range now. This will include elements starting at index 5.

**Swift 4.2**

```
array[5...]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one possible solution, there are probably a few more

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let endOfArray = Array(array[2..<array.endIndex]) // [3, 4, 5]
```

Or with dynamic index and range check

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let index = 2
let endOfArray : [Int]
if index < array.count {
  endOfArray = Array(array[index..<array.endIndex]) // [3, 4, 5]
} else {
  endOfArray = array
}
```

The re-initializition of the array is needed since the range subscription of `Array` returns `ArraySlice<Element>`

Comment: can the "2" be a variable like fromIndex?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the new method [removeFirst(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2886730-removefirst) in Swift 4

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array.removeFirst(2)
print(array) // [3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter`

```
func getEndOfArray( arr : [Int], fromIndex : Int? = 0) -> [Int] {
    let filteredArray = arr.filter({$0 <= fromIndex})

    return filteredArray
}
```

took the liberty of changing to `[Int]` for the sake of this example.